# How to reconnect after an interruption during an update?

Tags: updates

My daughter apparently interrupted an update to Ubuntu 12.04 turning down the computer and I am now asked to enter a login and a password and I have no  clue what to enter 
Can you help?

Comment: Try entering your username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Its your username login and your password